# multiple updates in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have some data like some prices 123.4561, 345.5671, 121.3432, 321.3452, 1234.3423 which needs to be updates as new prices for articles a,b,c,d,e respectively.

I have some 1000 such records.

I need to updates the new prices(like above) of these articles(all 1000) in a table.

Writing 1000 update statements would be a hectic work. I was thinking of using a cursor to do so. Still not able to take all the prices and link them up to its particular price.
The question is how to link a particular article with its new price and update it.

Can anyone please advise for any easier method? Thanks!

Comment: Where are the new prices? In a table? A file?

Comment: @David Aldridge in a file actually. I have all the new prices in a notepad .. you can suppose.

Comment: If the file is accessible to the server, or if it could be, then you can access it as an external table and use a MERGE statement to update your existing records. That would also add new ones, if any.

Comment: What data is in the file?  If it's just the new prices without anything else how can the correct row to be updated in the table be determined?  Please do not create another comment with this information - edit your post and add the info there.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis I have already mentioned in my question "I have some data like some prices 123.4561, 345.5671, 121.3432, 321.3452, 1234.3423 which needs to be updates as new prices for articles a,b,c,d,e RESPECTIVELY." I have both article and its respective new price data. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Assuming that both the article name and the new price are in your file, use UTL_FILE.FOPEN to open your file.  In an infinite loop inside a BEGIN block, use UTL_FILE.GET_LINE to read in the file.  Parse the article name and price out.  Convert the price to a number, then update your table using the article and price you read in.  Loop back and read the next line.  Trap any NO_DATA_FOUND exception thrown by the GET_LINE to force an exit from the loop.  Close the file.  Commit the transaction.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the format or data? if your notepad has lines like

```
art1,price1 
art2,price2
art3,price3
```

you can import this information into a table in database(best in your case is to use the import optio in SQL Developer, Toad, or whatever IDE you use),

and then issue an update:

```
update table_articles a
set price = (select price from import_table where price = a.price);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
UPDATE table1 SET price = 
CASE articles
 WHEN 'a' THEN 123.4561 
 WHEN 'b' THEN  345.5671
 ...
END   
WHERE articles IN ('a','b',....)
```

Comment: I already had this thing in mind..  I'm looking for a way to apply some loop and the price gets updated for article respectively. Is any way?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm).

The following is standard SQL:

```
WITH source
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ( 'a' ,  123.4561 ), 
                     ( 'b' ,  345.5671 ), 
                     ( 'c' ,  121.3432 ), 
                     ( 'd' ,  321.3452 ), 
                     ( 'e' , 1234.3423 )
             ) AS T ( articles , price )
     )
MERGE INTO YourTable
   USING source
      ON source.articles = YourTable.articles
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET price = source.price;
```

Something very close to this is supported by Oracle. Note the common table expression (CTE) may be replaced with a staging base table.